# Написал формы регистрации и входа, сомневаюсь в грамотности кода

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, написал код, но очень сомневаюсь в его грамотности, хотя все и работает: вводим логин и пароль, они записываются в массивы, и, если мы хотим войти под этим логином, вводим данные из массивов. Если данные совпадают то выводиться `alert( login + (' вошёл на сайт')`, а если нет - `alert( login + (' ошибка входа')`.
Есть ли у меня ошибки в грамотности написания этого кода или все вообще очень плохо?

HTML разметка

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text" id='createLogin'>
        <input type="password"  id='createPswrd'>
        <input type="button" id='register' value='Зарегестрироваться'>
    </form>

    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id='myLogin'>
        <input type="password"  id='myPswrd'>
        <input type="button" id='sign_in' value='Войти'>
    </form>
```

И сам скрипт

```
 'use strict'
// Создаем объект, в который записываются логины и пароли пользователей при регистрации. 
var usersInformation = {
  users: [], 
  passwords: [],
  // Создаем метод, который будет проверять правильность введенных данных при нажатии на кнопку 'Войти'
  checkPassword: function(login, pswrd) {
    if (this.users.indexOf(login) !== -1 && this.passwords.indexOf(pswrd) !== -1) {
      this.loginDone(true, login)
    } else {
      this.loginDone(false, login);
    } 
  },

  // Создаем метод, который будет выводить результат работы метода checkPassword 
  loginDone: function(result, login) {
    alert( login + (result ? ' вошёл на сайт' : ' ошибка входа') );
  }
}

// При клике на кнопку 'Зарегестрироваться' запускается эта функция.
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('register').onclick = function () {
    // Записываем значения инпутов в переменные
    var login = document.getElementById('createLogin').value;
    var pswrd = document.getElementById('createPswrd').value;
    // Создаем проверку на наличие пустых полей в инпутах
    if (login == '' || pswrd == '') {
      alert('Заполните все поля');
    } 
    // Если пустых полей нету, то записываем значения инпутов ключи объекта usersInformation
    else {
      usersInformation.users.push(login);
      usersInformation.passwords.push(pswrd);
    }
    // Проверяем уникальность вводимого логина
    if (usersInformation.users.length !== 0) {
      // Если длина не равна нулю, то запускаем цикл по массиву, не включая добавленный при клике логин
      for (var i = 0; i < usersInformation.users.length - 1; i++) {
        // Если в массиве до этого уже есть такой логин, то удаляем добавленный при клике логин и пароль
        if (usersInformation.users[i] == login) {
          usersInformation.users.pop(user.users[i]);
          usersInformation.passwords.pop(user.passwords[i]);
          alert('Введите другой логин')
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}

// При клике на кнопку войти запускается эта функция.
document.getElementById('sign_in').onclick = function () {
  // Записываем значения инпутов в переменные
  var login = document.getElementById('myLogin').value;
  var pswrd = document.getElementById('myPswrd').value;
  // Вызываем метод checkPassword с аргументами инпутов для 'Войти'
  usersInformation.checkPassword.call(usersInformation, login, pswrd);
}
```

Comment: ты уверен, что работает правильно?

Comment: Я просто сейчас прохожу объекты в js и мне важно попрактиковаться с ними

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [метод `pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) не принимает параметров. Следовательно вызовы `usersInformation.users.pop(user.users[i]);` и `usersInformation.users.pop();` эквивалентны и в результате будет удален именно **последний** элемент массива.
2. следующую строку `usersInformation.checkPassword.call(usersInformation, login, pswrd);` можно записать проще - `usersInformation.checkPassword(login, pswrd);`. В данном случае нет смысла использовать `call`, так как `this` внутри `checkPassword` и так будет указывать на `usersInformation`.
3. Странная логика в методе регистрации: зачем добавлять элементы, потом проверять их и потом удалять, если сначала можно проверить и уже решить стоит ли добавлять или нет.
4. Вероятно логическая ошибка в `checkPassword`: сейчас любому зарегистрированному юзеру подойдет любой зарегистрированный пароль. Например, в случае если есть два пользователя `users: ['user1', 'user2']`, и два пароля `passwords: ['pwd1', 'pwd2']`, то проверка в данной функции вернет `true` для любой из комбинаций:

   ```
   'user1', 'pwd1'
   'user1', 'pwd2'
   'user2', 'pwd1'
   'user2', 'pwd2'
   ```
5. Сама функция выполняет сразу несколько дел: и проверяет параметры, и выводит сообщение. Лучше оставить что-то одно.
6. Вместо использования массивов `users` и `passwords` напрямую при регистрации, лучше само добавление вынести в функцию объекта `usersInformation` в которую передавать введенные значение. Это позволит собрать работу с информацией о пользователе в одном месте.
7. Проверять наличие объекта в массиве можно с помощью функций [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) если нужно найти индекс, либо [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), если нужно просто проверить присутствует элемент или нет.
8. В принципе можно отказаться от использования двух массивов и использовать объект, в котором ключами будут являться логины, а значениями - пароли. Это позволит избежать многократных проходов по массиву для поиска и проверок уже залогиненных пользователей.
9. Сообщения лучше выводит не с помощью `alert`, который блокирует выполнение скриптов, а либо в `console`, для проверки, либо в какой-либо элемент непосредственно на странице.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли)

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую. Полностью согласен с ответом выше. От себя добавлю:

`usersInformation.users.length !== 0` не имеет смысла, можно просто `usersInformation.users.length`

Всегда по возможности используйте строгое сравнение `===`

Если только начали изучение JS, сразу смотрите на стандарт es2015 es2017,  потом переучиваться будет сложнее. А именно используйте объявление переменных с помощью `let` и `const`, которые находятся в области видимости блока { ... }

А вот объявление `var usersInformation` в  вашем случае запишет значение в объект window, а это самое что ни на есть **bad practice**. Как минимум весь ваш скрипт лучше обернуть самовызывающиеся функцией :

```
 (function () {
    // код функции 
 }());
```

Comment: не совсем корректное утверждение, ни let, ни const, ни var сами по себе не создают областей видимости

Comment: Да, верно. В попыхах написал. Не создают, а находятся.

Comment: поправь формулировку в ответе